# Find Out Connected clients IP's?

Tags: c#, ip-address

How to find out Connected Clients Ip Address. And how we can store that address to an array of datatype **IPAddress**?

Comment: Need more info on the context.  Are you running a webserver?  Some other sort of server?  Some kind of p2p app?

Comment: no. i have one small application of server and client. My reqment is find out the ip address of the connected clients in server.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [RemoteEndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint(VS.80).aspx) of your socket:

> If you are using a connection-oriented
>   protocol, the RemoteEndPoint property
>   gets the EndPoint that contains the
>   remote IP address and port number to
>   which the Socket is connected. If you
>   are using a connectionless protocol,
>   RemoteEndPoint contains the default
>   remote IP address and port number with
>   which the Socket will communicate. You
>   must cast this EndPoint to an
>   IPEndPoint before retrieving any
>   information. You can then call the
>   IPEndPoint.Address method to retrieve
>   the remote IPAddress, and the
>   IPEndPoint.Port method to retrieve the
>   remote port number.

If you use higher level components like TcpListener and TcpClient then you can [access the underlying socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.client(VS.80).aspx) and retrieve the remote end point.

If you use other technologies like ASP.Net, WCF or Remoting then you must say so in your post.

To store an IPAddress you retrieve the underlying bytes using [IPAddress.GetAddressBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes.aspx). You reconstruct the address from the bytes using [the byte[] constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4k07yby.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Are we in Windows? Do you need to use this information inside an application or a console command could do the trick?

maybe you could try with **netstat -na** in a shell.